# How to find a id in a array of ids on a array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `find()` method:

```
// data:
demands = [
 {
  "name": "first demand",
  "process": "31839",
  "categoryID": [
  {
   "_id": "1234",
   "name": "first",
   "color": "green"
  },
  {
   "_id": "1235",
   "name": "second",
   "color": "red"
  }
  ]
 },
 {
  "name": "second demand",
  "process": "90123",
  "categoryID": [
  {
   "_id": "4321",
   "name": "third",
   "color": "black"
  },
  {
   "_id": "1357",
   "name": "fourth",
   "color": "yellow"
  }
  ]
 }
]
```

```
// find:
if(demands.find((element) => element.categoryID._id === content.id)) {
  alert('find it!');
} else {
  alert('cant find it!');
}
```

But i always get undefined, so how can i get a id in a array of nested objects?

I have also tried using map and find or find inside another find, but none of them worked. I'm a beginner in javascript and have no clue in what to do.

Comment: Your `demands` is an absolutely invalid JSON https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Looks like your "categoryID" should be an array of objects

Comment: categoryID is *also* an array; you need to iterate it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should have double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: i miss write it, but my json have double quotes already.

Answer (score 0):

Since categoryID is an array, it should be accessed with an index. The correct way to access id is with an index after categoryID, e.g. `element.categoryID[0]._id` .

Comment: It is now after editing; it was not before.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem like this:

```
let flag = false;
    const findcategory = demands.map(
      (demand) => demand.categoryID.filter((category) => category._id === content._id),
    );

    findcategory.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.length !== 0) {
        flag = true;
      }
    });

    if (!flag) {
      // do this
    } else {
      // do that
    }
```

I dont think this is the most optimized method, but it worked!